# for using our equipment

Tags: meaning, gerunds, infinitives, time

> a. They paid a large sum **for using** our equipment.

> b. They paid a large sum **to use** our equipment.

Can one tell whether we were paid before they used our equipment or after they used our equipment?

---

> c. I paid him 100 dollars **for driving** around in his car for the weekend.

> d.  I paid him 100 dollars **to drive** around in his car for the weekend.

Can one tell whether the payment was made before or after the weekend in question?

---

The reason I have two sets of sentences is that I suspect that maybe 'use' might be a verb whose usage might be different to other verbs. That is just a suspicion, and probably a silly one.

I think the infinitive should be used when the action is supposed to take place after the payment and the 'for+gerund' construction could be used in either case, but I am not sure.

This question resembles the one I already asked, but here the agent of the infinitive or the gerund is the subject of the sentence.

Comment: I'm confused about the first pair. You say, "...they are using our equipment". This means right now, so they couldn't have paid after they used the equipment.

Comment: I am sorry. You are correct. That sentence has no business there.. I will delete it.  I was a bit confused myself when I was posting the question. I wanted to make sure it was understood that 'they' were the agent of 'using' and 'to use', but that is obvious. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

In neither pair of sentences is there any indication about when the payment was made. It could have been before, after or even some time during the equipment use / car driving. As far as I am aware the verb "to use" is nothing special in this respect.

Comment: Thank you so much Peter. How about: "The 100 dollars I paid him was to drive around in his car for the weekend." Could I have paid him after the weekend in question?

Comment: @azz That question is a bit more subjective. "The 100 dollars I paid him **was to drive** around in his car for the weekend." Would probably be interpreted by most as payment in advance, before the driving took place. "*here is $100 to go and drive*".

"The 100 dollars I paid him **for driving** around in his car for the weekend." could be taken as payment after the event.  "*here's $100 for having driven*" **BUT** this is by no means certain and payment could still have taken place at any time before, during or after in both cases.

Others will probably disagree with this interpretation.